# What is Ruby Coverage.c is and what is it for?

Tags: ruby

I came across this module in the Stdlib: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/coverage/rdoc/Coverage.html

Reading through that page, I'm not too clear on what this means:

> the number of line execution by the interpreter. A nil value means
>   coverage is disabled for this line (lines like else and end)

What is "number of line execution" and what is the "coverage" of a line?

I can't find any documentation on it or any mention of what it's for. Any ideas?

Comment: Well the page you linked to has a decent description and is actually documentation for it. What do you want to know that isn't already said there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "number of line execution" is, as you might expect, the number of times a line has been executed by the interpreter during execution of the program.

Let's look at the example in the documentation with the results added to the original code as comments.

```
[foo.rb]
s = 0           # executed once
10.times do |x| # once
  s += x        # ten times
end             # not analyzed
                # not analyzed
if s == 45      # once
  p :ok         # once
else            # not analyzed
  p :ng         # not executed
end             # not analyzed
[EOF]

require "coverage.so"
Coverage.start
require "foo.rb"
p Coverage.result  #=> {"foo.rb"=>[1, 1, 10, nil, nil, 1, 1, nil, 0, nil]}
```

The "coverage" is the analysis of how many times each line is executed.

I assume that this module would be useful to see if you have decent "code coverage" with your tests, i.e. check if the tests actually go through all the code or if there are parts that are never executed.

Using the same example in that context, this coverage analysis tells you that the `else p :ng` part is not exectued and might not be tested.

Answer (score 1):

> What is "number of line execution" and what is the "coverage" of a
>   line?

**"number of line execution"** => The number of times that line was executed when the code was run.

**"coverage"** => The number of times each line in a program executes.

Read this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage